# Removing 'default' annotation on storageclass AKS does not persist

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm trying to set a new default storage class in our Azure Kubernetes Service. (1.15.10). I've tried a few things but the behavior is strange to me.

I've created a new storage class `custom`, set it to be the default storage class and then I remove the is-default-class from the `default` storageclass.

default-storage-class.yml:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: custom
parameters:
  cachingmode: ReadOnly
  kind: Managed
  storageaccounttype: Standard_LRS
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

and the commands:

```
# create new storage class "custom"
kubectl apply -f ./default-storage-class.yml
# set storageclass as new default
kubectl patch storageclass custom -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
# remove default storage class from default
kubectl patch storageclass default -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"false"}}}'
```

At first, it seems to be working fine:

```
$kubectl get sc
custom (default)   kubernetes.io/azure-disk   6d23h
default            kubernetes.io/azure-disk   14m
```

But within a minute, without changing anything:

```
$kubectl get sc
custom (default)   kubernetes.io/azure-disk   6d23h
default (default)  kubernetes.io/azure-disk   16m
```

I'm probably missing something here, but no idea what.

If I do a `kubectl describe sc default` in the minute it hasn't changed back :

```
storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=false,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=false
```

And a moment later:

```
storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=false
```

Comment: why do you need to change the default? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I ran into an issue with the default storage class and a deployment. The deployment failed because it needed a different storage account type. (default is StandardSSD_LRS and it needed Standard_LRS). 

I figured it would be best to create a new storageclass and set the storage account type to Standard_LRS for future deployment. 

The reason I want to make it default, is because I don't want to specifiy the storage class for all my deployments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of testing, found the only way to make the default to be not default was by updating not only the `storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class` annotation but `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` annotation as well.

```
kubectl patch storageclass default -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"false", "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"allowVolumeExpansion\":true,\"apiVersion\":\"storage.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"StorageClass\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class\":\"false\"},\"labels\":{\"kubernetes.io/cluster-service\":\"true\"},\"name\":\"default\"},\"parameters\":{\"cachingmode\":\"ReadOnly\",\"kind\":\"Managed\",\"storageaccounttype\":\"StandardSSD_LRS\"},\"provisioner\":\"kubernetes.io/azure-disk\"}"}}}'
```

After applying this, default StorageClass stayed non-default.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. `kubectl get sc default > default-sc.yaml`
2. Change storage account type in the YAML file
3. `kubectl delete sc default`
4. `kubectl apply -f default-sc.yaml`

Just make sure there is not much time gap between step 3 and step 4 otherwise the default storage class will be created again before you could perform step 4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try this first thing tomorrow morning. Do you happen to know why I can't set another 'default' or why it keeps changing back? I should be able to set another storage class as default right?